# C memory issues on file import

Tags: c, import, valgrind

I'm writing a pretty long program that includes a lot of data importing and I started getting an error `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`. I looked around and this seemed to be caused by `free()` functions. I then commented all such functions in my program and the error still happened. All I could find is that this is probably caused by memory issues and that I should run Valgrind. So I did, and it returned me a whole bunch of errors mostly related to my import functions. In particular this one:

```
void import_bn(int depth, int idx, float pdata[4][depth]) {

    // [0][:] is gamma, [1][:] is beta, [2][:] is moving mean, [3][:] is moving variance

    // Define name from index
    char name[12]; // maximum number of characters is "paramxx.csv" = 11
    sprintf(name, "param%d.csv", idx);

    // open file
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen(name, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        perror("fopen()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char c = fgetc(fptr); // generic char
    char s[13];           // string, maximum number of characters is "-xxx.xxxxxxx" = 12
    char* a;              // pointer for strtof

    for (int t = 0; t < 4; ++t) { // type
    for (int d = 0; d < depth; ++d) { // depth

        //skip S
        if (c == 'S') {c = fgetc(fptr);c = fgetc(fptr);}

        // write string
        for (int i=0; c != '\n'; ++i) {
            s[i] = c;
            c = fgetc(fptr);
        }

        float f = strtof(s,&a); // convert to float
        pdata[t][d] = f;     // save on array
        c = fgetc(fptr);
    }}

    fclose(fptr);
}
```

The file this is supposed to be opening always has the format:

```
0.6121762
1.5259982
1.6705754
0.6907939
0.5508608
1.2173915
S
2.2555487
2.9224594
-1.6631562
-1.2156529
1.6944195
1.0379710
...etc
```

So basically they are float32s separated by '\n' and each batch is separated by an "S". This represents a multidimensional array, and in the case of this function there are always exactly 4 batches, but sizes vary.

One of the errors that appeared a lot in Valgrind was `Use of uninitialised value of size 8` at the `float f = strtof(s,&a);` line. Am I using `strtof()` wrong?

The full results from Valgrind can be found here: https://pastebin.com/rKwTUgut

Comment: You forgot to add a null terminator to `s`.

Comment: Since you are now getting a segmentation fault, you may want to investigate it in a debugger, if possible, to see exactly where it is occuring.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel right, sorry. I'm still new here, don't quite know how things work. Speaking of which would you rather I make a new question with the current problem or keep updating this one?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I will work on that, still need to learn to use the debugger on the IDE I'm using.

Comment: @Ricardo: Since the original problem with the `"munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer"` error message was solved, it may be appropriate to ask a new question for your new problem with the segmentation fault. However, you should generally use the debugger to isolate the problem and to create a [mre] of the problem, otherwise your question will likely get downvoted.

Comment: @Ricardo: Maybe it is not appropriate to use a debugger yet, if valgrind has already pointed out a problem with the line `pdata[t][d] = f;`. However, if I understand the information you provided in the question correctly, you stated that you still get "this same error in Valgrind" after applying the fix mentioned in the answer. If I understand that statement correctly, it means that Valgrind was still complaining about `s[i] = c;`. According to the information in the question, only after adding the `assert` statements did Valgrind start complaining about `pdata[t][d] = f;`. (...)

Comment: @Ricardo: (...) However, that does not make sense, as the `assert` statements should not change the behavior of the program, unless an `assert` condition is false and therefore an error message is triggered. Therefore, I believe that the information in your question must be incorrect or misleading.

Comment: @Ricardo: I suspect that changing `char s[11];` to `char s[13];` caused the valgrind message to change, so that it now complains about `pdata[t][d] = f;` instead of `s[i] = c;`. I therefore suspect that the information in your question which claims that it was caused by adding the `assert` statements was incorrect.

Comment: @Ricardo: As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with the code in the function `import_bn`, assuming that the dimensions of the passed array really are supposed to be `4` and `depth`. In that case, the problem must be that the calling function is passing a pointer that is either wrong or there was insufficient memory allocated for the array.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I used the debugger for a bit, and the program seems to exit at `fclose(fptr);` whatever that means.

Comment: @Ricardo: I suspect that `fclose` is failing due to the memory getting corrupted by the line `pdata[t][d] = f;`. I am assuming this because Valgrind is complaining about that line. Therefore, I would have to see the function that calls the function `import_bn`, to see if the memory that is being passed to `import_bn` has been allocated properly.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I also re-tested the program and indeed, removing the `assert` command causes the error count to go up to 20 instead of 17. However, I can't seem to find what these errors are, it just mentions 16 `Invalid write of size 4` and 1 `Invalid write of size 1`.

Comment: @Ricardo: If Valgrind is still complaing about the line `pdata[t][d] = f;`, then that is certainly the first place to look. If that line is causing Valgrind to complain, then this is probably due to the `pdata` function argument not pointing to properly allocated memory. Therefore, I would have to see the code of the function that calls the function `import_bn`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel import_bn is called 5 times by the same function, at the 5th it crashes. I double checked, I don't think I'm allocating the memory wrong. Although, here's an idea: I believe the 5th time import_bn is ran is the first time it has to import numbers of sizes in the hundreds, or negative hundreds. Considering pdata is a single float, is there  a problem passing a number too precise to it?

Comment: @Ricardo: `pdata` is a pointer to a variable-length array of type `float`. It is not a floating-point number itself. Pointers are never floating-point, so there never is an issue with precision. Therefore, this cannot be reason for writing to memory out of bounds.

Comment: @Ricardo: When you wrote `"Considering pdata is a single float"`, are you saying that `pData` is only pointing to a single `float`? It should be pointing to `4*depth` `float`s, otherwise the function `import_bn` will write out of bounds.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Oh no, I meant a single *precision* float. I checked, the number being received by the function as "depth" in this case is 96. And the file has 4x96 numbers.

Comment: @Ricardo: If depth is `96`, then when `import_bn` is called, its argument `pdata` must point to a memory buffer that is at least `96*4*sizeof(float)` bytes large. Otherwise, the function `import_bn` will write out of bounds of the memory buffer. The Valgrind message seems to be implying that insufficient memory was allocated and that the function `import_bn` is indeed writing to `pdata` out of bounds.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel OK I found the bug. You were right, I was allocating memory wrong, I was using the size of the input, not the depth, which is a number that was *larger* than depth for the last 4 times it was ran, but now just became *smaller* than it, making it write out of memory. Thanks for the help, should I delete the question or leave it here?

Comment: @Ricardo: Deleting the question would not be fair towards the person who answered your question. Also, you cannot delete the question when the answer has at least 1 upvote. See this official help page for further information: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Ah, right! Thanks for the information, I wasn't aware.

Comment: @Ricardo: Does Valgrind still report anything? Or does it now provide a clean message? By the way, you can easily disable all `assert` statements for performance reasons by `#define NDEBUG` or by compiling with `-DNDEBUG`. You should do this for production builds (not debug builds).

Comment: @Ricardo: You may want to delete your updates to the question, because they are no longer relevant, since the problem was not in the code that you posted.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thank you for all the help! I managed to debug the rest of the errors in Valgrind, there are none now. I will add hte `#define NDEBUG` statement for performance, and I will delete the updates here then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to `strtof()` must be a null-terminated string. You're not adding a null terminator after the `// write string` loop.

```
        int i;
        for (i=0; c != '\n'; ++i) {
            s[i] = c;
            c = fgetc(fptr);
        }
        s[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: Wow, that went from 310362 errors to 20. Thanks. However, there is still an error that happens in line `s[i] = c;`, I'm updating it in the question.

Comment: @Ricardo: Are you sure that you are not writing to `s` out of bounds? This will occur if `i>=11` when the loop runs.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes, that was a problem, I just fixed it for all functions. It still exists in error, though.

Comment: @Ricardo: When you say `"this same error with Valgrind"`, are you saying that `valgrind` is still complaining about the line `s[i] = c;`? If that is the case, then I suggest that you add the line `assert( 0 <= i && i <= 12 );` above the line `s[i] = c;` and try running your program again. Note that you must `#include <assert.h>` in order to use the [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert) macro.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Did that for all 4 import functions, now I have 17 errors. Will update at the question.

Comment: @Ricardo: Adding the `assert` macro is only supposed to verify that you are not writing to the array out of bounds, and it should provide an error message if that assumption is wrong and abort the program. Otherwise, it should not change the behavior of the program and it should not change what `valgrind` reports. Therefore, I am surprised that you are now saying that `valgrind` is reporting something else, but you are not mentioning anything about the `assert` macro printing an error message. You may want to change it to `assert( 0 );` to see whether what it looks like when it is triggered.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel That *is* weird. Just to make sure I ran the exact same code again without the 4 asserts and it returned me 20 errors. With them it's 17. I will update the question with the answer using `assert( 0 );`

Comment: @Ricardo: Ok, the `assert( 0 );` was only for testing purposes. It seems that the `assert` macro is working properly, since it was triggered. You can now change it back again to `assert( 0 <= i && i <= 12 );`. In your original question, you say that you are getting the error message `"munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer"`. However, in the "UPDATE", you say that you are "still" getting a "segmentation fault"`. Do you mean the same thing? Or is this segmentation fault a new symptom?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Right, I forgot to mention that. The `"munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer"` error disappeared, now it only exits with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)
`.

Comment: @Ricardo: I suggest that we move this discussion away from the answer to the comments section of the question, so that the answerer doesn't get notified of every new message. He is probably getting spammed with notifications.